# Stylelint 'Unknown rule declaration-property-value-blacklist' error on every css file

Tags: stylelint

While running Stylelint against CSS files, every file has an output with the following error. It is odd that the error appears on the first line/character of each file.

`1:1 x Unknown rule declaration-property-value-blacklist`

Answer (score 2):

Stylelint shows the "Unknown rule ..." problem when it encounters a rule in the configuration object that it doesn't recognise.

The `declaration-property-value-blacklist` rule [was removed in version 14.0.0](https://stylelint.io/CHANGELOG#1400) of Stylelint. It was replaced by the [`declaration-property-value-disallowed-list`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/declaration-property-value-disallowed-list) rule. You should update your configuration object to use that rule instead.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. It appears that the error is related to using stylelint-config-airbnb. https://issuemode.com/issues/airbnb/css/10818973

Answer (score 1):

There is a compatibility error between Stylelint 14.x and the stylelint-config-airbnb plugin. https://issuemode.com/issues/airbnb/css/10818973